# ¿Cómo guardar valor en un archivo de configuración?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo una pequeño inconveniente, en un proyecto que estoy haciendo, necesito guardar una IP (digitada por el usuario que utilizará la app) para realizar la conexión a un servidor.

Tengo entendido que un servidor debe tener una IP fija, pero en este caso los usuarios de la app utilizan IP's dinámicas, los usuarios son empresas pequeñas que como que no les importa mucho eso así que no se complican en ponerles direcciones fijas.

Bueno la idea de esta función es no tener que digitar la IP en el código fuente, además como las IP's van a estar en constante cambio, necesito ese control para que la app no falle.
¿Alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?  ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes guardar el valor de la IP en preferencias y al requerirlo puedes obtener el valor almacenado de ahí :

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "misdatos";

public void guardaIP(Context context, String valor) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("myIP", valor);
    editor.commit();
}



public String obtieneIP(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString("myIP", "");
}
```

---

Mediante los métodos puedes guardar el valor de la IP, como ejemplo suponiendo esta escrita en un EditText:

```
guardaIP(getApplicationContext(), EditTextIP.getText().ToString());
```

Para obtener el valor y agregarlo a tu EditText:

```
 EditTextIP.setText(obtieneIP(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Pero las SharedPreferences no son un archivo al fin y al cabo?

Comment: En realidad es un archivo .xml guardado en disco.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion +1 saludos

Comment: Tengo otra duda, al yo querer obtener la IP en distintas clases, por ejemplo Una clase conexión, ¿es el mismo método o tengo que utilizar otro?

Comment: Habiendo guardado en preferencias el valor, puedes obtener el valor en cualquier clase, solo recuerda que es importante el contexto para obtener el valor.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con el "contexto"?

Comment: El parametro que reciben los métodos: guardaIP(Context context, String valor)

Comment: Ok gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por nada, trata de implementar esto y si tienes duda comenta, saludos! =)

Comment: No termino de entender como lo puedo implementar en otra clase, estoy tratando de igualar una variable String a lo que tiene obternerIP, algo así  `IP = config.obtieneIP(context);` pero me marca un error, al ejecutarla, dice algo como "que esta nulo" pero yo ya tengo una IP guardada.